# Jquery problem onclick add class and remove class

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, if-statement

first time posting here. I'm a beginner in jquery and i ran into some grey area. Hopefully i can find my answer here and learn from it also :)

So i have a let's say 10 different div. All has the same class. And everytime I click on the div it has to add another class (in this case background-color in css). For that I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".menucardmenu").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("menucardmenu")) {
               $(this).addClass("backgroundmenucard");
    }
    else {
        alert ("condition false");
    }
  });
});
```

But the question now is, how can i make that only one div can have that background-color (in my case backgroundmenucard). Depending one which div the user click, that div will have the background-color, and the previous div (that was clicked) should reset it back to normal. I can do it with this right?:

> $(this).removeClass("backgroundmenucard");

does anyone know the answer to this???

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: I think the "else" block will never execute...am I wrong?

Comment: @Sayem no, you are not wrong. You might even say you're right `;-)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following:

```
$(".menucardmenu").click(function(){
    $(".backgroundmenucard").removeClass("backgroundmenucard");
     $(this).addClass("backgroundmenucard");
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r2Sua/

(I remove the `if` because it's useless in this case)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Thx you very much. Yes I was looking into the if-else statement so I used it for the basic. After that I was unsure what the purpose was since I it already works

Answer (score 2):

Remove from all...

```
$(".menucardmenu").removeClass("backgroundmenucard");
```

Then add to `this`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() // shorthand for document ready
{
    var $divs = $('div.menucardmenu'), // standard jQuery "cache" idiom
        BG_CLASS = 'backgroundmenucard'; // stay DRY, less prone to typos

    $divs.live('click', function() // use .live to bind only 1 event listener
    {   
        // remove the class from all divs
        $divs.removeClass(BG_CLASS);

        // add the class to this div
        $(this).addClass(BG_CLASS);
    }
  });
});
```

The `if($(this).hasClass("menucardmenu"))` check is completely unnecessary since you're already selecting elements which have that class. It will always evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menucardmenu').click(function(){
 $('.menucardmenu').removeClass('backgroundmenucard');
 $(this).addClass('backgroundmenucard');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```
$(".menucardmenu").not(this).removeClass("backgroundmenucard");
$(this).addClass("backgroundmenucard");
```

This way you don't remove and add the class to the specific (this) element

Comment: You're adding the class to `this` no matter what, so it really doesn't make a difference.